How can a function getattr from a specific call of itself?
I want to be able to do something like:
def func(var_name):
    x = 2
    y = 3
    return getattr(self, var_name)

And have
func("x")

return 2. Obviously the problem here is that the function call doesn't get passed itself, so I don't have access to a self that I can pass into getattr.
I thought this answer was a solution to this problem, but it returns f itself, rather than a specific call of it, so can't access variables computed while func runs.

Obviously in this toy example using getattr or something similar isn't necessary, but I have a more complicated situation where I think it might be.
This question has been poorly received, apparently because it's something people think I shouldn't want to do in the first place, so I want to explain why I want to do this: I am coding a pokemon battle game, and am trying to solve the problem of how to encode attacks that (may) have an effect back on the user, such as an attack that has the potential to give a moxie boost (you don't need to know what that means).
The way I addressed this problem is by giving the attack object an attribute which is a list of BackEffect objects. These objects would consist of a function do() which executes the effect, and information on when do should be executed, and what arguments do() needs, because different effects need access to different information. E.g. a moxie boost effect would need to be executed if the attack faints the opposing pokemon. The execute_attack() function would then be able to go through the list and call all the do functions that need to be called.
The original way I did this gets quite cluttered as you add more effects:
def execute_attack(attack, pokemon):
    DO VARIOUS OTHER THINGS WHICH PRODUCES VARIABLES USED BELOW
    attacker = attack.attacking_pokemon
    for b in attack.back_effects:
        if b.effect_type == "needs to know if hit":
            b.do(attacker, did_it_hit)
        elif b.effect_type == "needs to know if fainted":
            b.do(attacker, did_it_faint) 
        elif b.effect_type == "needs to know how much damage":
            b.do(attacker, how_much_damage) 

With more elifs needing to be added sometimes when new effects are implemented. This is clearly quite repetitive, so I wanted to find a way of doing this which avoids repetition, and which allows new BackEffects to be added without editing execute_attack(), as long as the relevant variables are already accessible to execute_attack().
For an object, this would be possible using getattr(), so I thought something like that was what I was looking for. The proposal to put everything in a dictionary is undesirable because I would either have to put everything in execute_attack() into a dictionary, or edit execute_attack() to move more variables into the dictionary whenever I add a new effect_type, making execute_attack() get larger and larger. It would make the rest of the code that isn't dealing with back effects look a lot messier if a lot of otherwise unrelated key variables that get used over and over again have to be retrieved from the same dictionary.
Using locals() doesn't have this problem, so it seems like a much nicer solution, for my specific purposes. I'm aware it can cause problems if unexpected things end up being asked for from execute_attack(), but the list of things that can be asked for is built in, so that shouldn't be an issue for me. I just don't want it to be built in in a very repetitive way to execute_attack(), which is already a long function. This also makes it easier to implement new effects.
Is using locals() still bad practice in my case? If so, why?
I didn't include this information initially because my last question was poorly received for going into unnecessary detail.

Maybe x and y should be keys in a dictionary so this is explicit and easier to understand. Trying to get a function to get a reference to itself is not common practice and will make for unnecessarily complex code.

@Mark I want to have the flexibility to call any variable that func has action to, and whilst it would be possible to put every variable func uses whilst running into a dictionary, I'm hoping there's a more natural/ less messy solution.

Can you clarify some things please? Do you mean with "f" the function "func"? Where is the "self" defined? What is wrong with using a dict like d = {"x": 2, "y": 3} and then retrieving the value with d["x"]? I believe you are messing up classes and functions in this example.

Callers of a function have no business knowing about local variables inside the function. Whatever you're trying to do, rethink the structure.

You want your functions to do well defined things, not have an endless amount of flexibility and potentially access anything from anywhere…

Local variables aren't attributes of functions, thus getattr etc. is a complete red herring.

@oskar I have corrected f to say func, thank you. The issue with a dictionary is that it would be messy for more complicated examples. The variables being accessed would be anything func computes while running. self isn't defined, I meant that to illustrate what I would lie to do, not as code that would actually work.

The caller can't know what is being computed; the function is a black box. The function has to document what arguments will produce sensible return value. Arguments are data, and variable names are code, not data.

If the function has so many ways to call it that is it messy for complex examples, the function may need to be refactored. If you look around at the millions (billions?) of lines of python code out there, people don't seem to have this problem. In fact, they actively avoid this sort of code because it couples the caller and the function — once you've done this you can't change function internals without changing all the places it is called. It's actually one of the main points of functions having their own variable scope.

"The duplicate target provides an alternative [..] inferior to the use of locals()" — The duplicate contains more than one answer, some of which also suggest locals(). It's just by far not the recommended solution.

Frankly, this should probably all be handled by better OOP structures, with more fine grained overloadable methods, proper interfaces, objects which express the results of attacks, and of course a big rule engine which can process all this. You're thinking way too small and localised here for what this problem really requires to be solved properly, maintainably and extensibly.

An alternative to needing to lookup certain variable names to pass the right one to a function: Unconditionally call b.do(did_it_hit, did_it_faint, how_much_damage, ...). The do method can use just the arguments it needs, ignoring the rest. The execute_attack function shouldn't need to know all the details, it can delegate that to code in a more appropriate place (in this case, the b.do methods).

You could even use keyword arguments to make it easier to extend the logic with more effects, without each effect needing to know the details that others care about: b.do(hit=did_it_hit, faint=did_it_faint, damage=how_much_damage, ...), and the do methods can be implemented as def do(self, *, damage, **kwargs) for an effect that cares only about the amount of damage.

Replace the last line of func with:
return locals()[var_name]


Ya beat me by 20 seconds Scott!

@JRiggles: Only because I posted the bare minimum.

but you guys are correct why the vote down or am i missing something

"correct" doesn't imply "useful".  Sometimes you have to see the question behind the question, and refuse the temptation to just answer the literal question.

@wim oh I see so it has be useful and correct. I usually feel if I get a vote down, I am wrong. haha! now i see thanks.
